# How to handle multiple touch inputs

Tags: input, libgdx

```
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {      
        //moving right touchscreen
        if(touchPos.x >= 310 && touchPos.x <= 445 && touchPos.y >= 770  &&touchPos.y <= 870 )
            man.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), man.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        //moving left touchscreen
        if(touchPos.x >= 70 && touchPos.x <= 220 && touchPos.y >= 770  &&touchPos.y <= 870 )
            man.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), man.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        if(touchPos.x >=1630  && touchPos.x <= 1815 && touchPos.y >= 740  &&touchPos.y <=  935 && man.b2body.getPosition().y <=0.22)
            man.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4f), man.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
```

The above is my code, when I run the application, my character can run right and left and jump but individually when pressed. How can I make my character jump while running. Handling two inputs?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are checking if touch is inside a square. Instead of checking if a touch is inside the bounds of all those coordinates, you could place some Rectangles and check if player touches them.

Or even better, use Scene2d to add buttons. This will make for much better and reliable input control. 
You can make invisible buttons if you don't want them to be seen.

[Brent Aureli made a nice tutorial for on-screen controles.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4Vqkp_ve3I)